# Android CheckBoxPreference minmum sdk version

Tags: android, android-4.0.3-ice-cream-sandwich

I am developing android application with following app build gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

and simple PreferenceFragment with xml configuration:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference android:title="Application Updates"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:summary="Simple check box preference."
    android:key="applicationUpdates" />
```

When I run app on device with api level 23 everything is ok but when I run the same code on emulator with api 15 I get error:

```
03-09 19:38:01.205 1541-1541/com.test.app E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
...
some code
...
03-09 19:38:01.205 1541-1541/com.test.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
some code
...
03-09 19:38:01.205 1541-1541/com.test.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_check_mat
```

I think that something is wrong with material design library but I am not sure and I don't know how to solve this problem. I want to run app on devices with sdk 15 but I can't. How I can fix this problem?

PS. When I remove CheckBoxPreference from xml configuration my app i working on api 15 and api 23.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. This problem was solved by adding:

```
aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
```

to app build gradle.